# python typing module: Mixin

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, typechecking

Is there any class under `typing` that behaves like a mixin?

For example

```
from typing import Union
class A:
  pass

class B:
  pass

class C:
  pass

class D(A, B, C):
  pass

# current: ab is A or B, but not both
def f(ab: Union[A, B]):
    pass

# ideal: ab is A and B
def f(ab: Mixin[A, B]):
    pass

f(D())
```

please notice how `D` is instance of `A` and `B`, but also `C`. This would be too much of a restriction for `f` (since `f` doesn't require `C`) and thus, the parameter `ab` is not necessarily of type `D` but `Mixin[A, B]`

If the `typing` module doesn't provide any option, is there anything more elegant than creating my own `class AB(A, B)`?

Comment: No, at least not yet, not without declaring a separate class or protocol to annotate with. But it can be noted that this has been elaborated on: Guido mentioned a `Intersection[t1, t2, …]` companion to `Union` as a "We might add" [in 2014](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#fundamental-building-blocks). Also, the Protocol PEP (2017) mentioned a `Proto = All[Proto1, Proto2, ...]`construct [as a rejected idea](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#provide-a-special-intersection-type-construct), commenting that it could easily be added in the future.

Comment: *[python - specify type with multiple bases (typing AND operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63108452)*, which was closed as a duplicate of this one, has an answer regarding the use of `Protocol`s.

Answer (score 6):

It seem to be impossible for now.

You can find a discussion about "Intersection" type in [python/typing#123](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) repository.

There is a similar feature on [PEP-544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) called *Protocol*, and you can merge mixins by merging mixin protocols.
There is an implementation of [PEP-544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) called [typing_extensions](https://github.com/python/typing/tree/master/typing_extensions). Maybe you can try that with this library.

Comment: Protocols are now in Python 3.8

Comment: I've tryed this solution on a TesCaseMixin but Protocol implements __init__() and for pytest is mandatory to not implement __init__() on a TestCase class