# How to express multiple inheritance in Python type hint?

Tags: python, python-typing

In Java, C#, a generic method can have a type parameter with constraint to define the interfaces that must be implemented.

```
static <T extends Iterable<Integer> & Comparable<Integer>> void test(T p) {

}
```

In Python, If I want to use type hint to specify that a variable must inherit classes A and B, how can I do it? I checked the typing module, it only has a Union which means the type of the variable can be any of the hint, not all of the hint.

Creating a new class C which inherits A and B seems a solution, but looks cumbersome.

Comment: If there is a class inheriting from A and B, then you should place that class there. It is a type hint, not an inheritance hint.

Comment: More than one class can inherits A and B, like T1(A, B, C), T2(A, B, D). Then I define a function whose parameter must inherit A and B: "def func(obj)". I want to use type hint to show this requirement.

Comment: Well that requirement is not a type. You should remember that unlike Java and C, Python is not a statically typed language. It uses the concept of duck-typing. So these type **hints** serve different purpose than interfaces in Java. They are mainly for documentation and IDE features like auto suggestion.

Comment: It would look weird if this is not supported. Union in typing module can express "any", while "all" can't be expressed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python typing module: Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912576/python-typing-module-mixin)

Answer (score 3):

That class definition is equivalent to:

```
class MyIter(Iterator[T], Generic[T]):
    ...
```

You can use multiple inheritance with Generic:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Sized, Iterable, Container, Tuple

T = TypeVar('T')

class LinkedList(Sized, Generic[T]):
    ...

K = TypeVar('K')
V = TypeVar('V')

class MyMapping(Iterable[Tuple[K, V]],
                Container[Tuple[K, V]],
                Generic[K, V]):
    ...
```

Subclassing a generic class without specifying type parameters assumes Any for each position. In the following example, MyIterable is not generic but implicitly inherits from Iterable[Any]:

```
from typing import Iterable

class MyIterable(Iterable):  # Same as Iterable[Any]
    ...
```

Generic metaclasses are not supported.

Comment: Do you need to specify `Generic[K, V]`? Is `(Iterable[Tuple[K, V]], Container[Tuple[K, V]])` not enough?

Comment: See [mypy's documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#defining-sub-classes-of-generic-classes)