# Type Hinting a Factory Classmethod on a Mixin Class taking a Class Argument using Multiple Inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, type-hinting

Given I have a class somewhere inheriting from two other classes:

```
class Mother:
    pass

class Father:
    pass

class Child(Mother, Father):
    pass
```

And a Mixin class providing a factory method for `Child`:

```
class FactoryMixin:
    def make(self: (FactoryMixin and Child)) -> (FactoryMixin and Child):
        return self.__class__()
```

What is the correct type hint to express the union of those classes as in `(FactoryMixin and Child)`? Don't suggest `typing.Union` please because `Union[A, B]` means `A` **or** `B`, not `A` **and** `B` ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)). This is a minimal example, the actual situation is much more complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python typing module: Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912576/python-typing-module-mixin)

Comment: @Georgy but there is no solution there

Comment: @Patrick -- I think the overall gist of the proposed duplicate is correct though: there's no real way of constructing an intersection type in the PEP 484 typing ecosystem; the workarounds probably involve using protocols in some way. In this particular case, you could maybe switch to using a TypeVar, make the [self variable generic](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self), and side-step the whole problem -- but that's a patch for this specific scenario. In general, I think the typing ecosystem + mixins will mix awkwardly.