# Type hinting values that are multiple types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

My question is different than the title implies (I don't know how to summarize the question so I'm having a hard time googling).

I do not want a Union type. Union[A, B] says that the type can be either of type A, or of type B.

I need to the opposite. I want it to mean that it is both type A and B, which is possible in python because of mixins.

That is, I need to type hint a function such that I know the arguments passed will be of a class that has both A and B as parents, as my function uses methods from both mixins. A Union type hint allows passing something that has A without B which should not be allowed.

Example

```
from typing import Union

class A(object):
    def a(self):
        return True

class B(object):
    def b(self):
        return True

class C(A, B):
    pass

def foo(d: Union[A,B]) -> bool: #need something other than Union! 
    print(d.a() and d.b())
```

I need d to be an A and a B. But currently it allows me to send things that are A without being B, and errors when it tries to call the non-existent function

```
>>> foo(A())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'b'
>>> foo(B())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> foo(C())
True
```

Further I'd like to note, that the type can't just be `d: C`. This is because there are many classes that have A and B, and it would be a ridiculously long Union that would need to be maintained.

Comment: This is called an "intersection" type (as opposed to a union type), FWIW. I don't think it exists exactly in the type hinting system. Some discussion here: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213

Comment: You could define a class `C` that inherits from `A` and `B` and does nothing, and inherit from that in your many classes that currently inherit from both `A` and `B`. But it's not a pretty solution.

Comment: @L3viathan Yeah, that looks like the sad truth I'm heading toward. Surprised this feature has been in discussion for 5 years and never implemented. It seems natural if you include Union.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python typing module: Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912576/python-typing-module-mixin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use next OOP approach.

1. Create interface - it's abstract class in python, which can show methods, which implements concrete classes. Example:

   ```
   from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

   class MyAB(ABC):
       @abstractmethod
       def a(self):
           pass

       @abstractmethod
       def b(self):
           pass


   class A(object):
       def a(self):
           return True


   class B(object):
       def b(self):
           return True


   class ConcreteClass(MyAB, A, B):
       pass


   def foo(d: MyAB):
       print(d.a() and d.b())


   c = ConcreteClass()

   foo(c)
   ```

2. You say - parameter `d` in function `foo` can be able using two methods `a` and `b`. Thats all that you need.

Comment: Accepting because this seems to be the best we can do given the current type hinting libraries.