# How can I specify a subtype of multiple types (including general types, like Callable) in Python type annotations?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, typing, typechecking

One obvious example of this is multiple inheritance: if I have classes `Foo` and `Bar`, I can make a class `Baz` that inherits from both (`class Baz(Foo, Bar): ...`). However, I could also make another class with a different behavior, which still inherits from both `Foo` and `Bar`... or I could inherit from a third class, which makes a completely different type. Obviously, this is a niche use case, but is this supported in Python type annotations? In the example case, I don't want to write `Baz` specifically - I only need to know the fact that a type is both `Foo` and `Bar`, but it can also be anything else. I was thinking something along the lines of `param: Foo | Bar` or `param: typing.Multiple[Foo, Bar]`.

My specific use case: I want to use the `Callable` syntax to specify parameter and return types (e.g. `Callable[..., bool]`) but I also need to make sure that the argument is a `FunctionType`, i.e. not a class or builtin_function_or_method. Of course, I could just specify this in the docstring - but is this supported in type annotations in a way that will work with type checkers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python typing module: Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912576/python-typing-module-mixin). Also see [the linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/44912576/), maybe you will find something useful there.

Comment: @Georgy that led me to the Protocol class - so thanks for the link, but this doesn't solve my problem because Protocols don't support general types, such as Callable. However, I did end up seeing [this issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) which indicates that a proper Intersection type isn't supported yet, but might be in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited version of this through the Protocol class ([PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/), [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)) - however, it only supports type variables (`Protocol[T]`) and concrete types (`class MyProtocol(FunctionType, Protocol)`), but not general types like Any, Union, Callable, Iterator, etc. So, the example case in the question can be implemented as

```
class FooAndBar(Foo, Bar, typing.Protocol): ...
```

but the use case mentioned below seems to be impossible ([might be possible eventually](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213)), so for now I'd either define a Protocol with just the members you need, use a string as the type hint, or specify this in a docstring.

Additional note: if you use an IntelliJ IDE, you can write

```
assert isinstance(param, (Foo, Bar))
```

which will, for the purposes of type checking, achieve the same result as a hypothetical `param: Intersection[Foo, Bar]` in any further code.