# python - specify type with multiple bases (typing AND operator)

Tags: python, python-typing

I understand (as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945261/how-to-specify-multiple-return-types-using-type-hints) and [the docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) that a type hint of `X` **or** `Y` can be expressed as:

```py
Union[X,Y]
```

But how does one express a type hint of `X` **and** `Y`? This would be useful when expressing that the object in question must be a subclass of both `X` and `Y`.

The following example works as long as all classes that inherit both `X` and `Y` are known in advance:

```py
class X: pass
class Y: pass
class A(X,Y): pass
class B(X,Y): pass

def some_function(arg: Union[A,B]): 
    pass
    # do stuff with arg that only depends on inherited members from X and Y
```

But what if another package which depends on the code above defines:

```py
class C(X,Y): pass
```

`C` also will work in `some_function` by design. I am looking for a better type hint to use instead of `Union[X,Y]` that includes any possible class that sub-classes both `X` and `Y`.

I understand a workaround could be to define:

```py
class XY(X,Y): pass
```

And then use it as a base class and type hint:

```py
class A(XY): pass
class B(XY): pass
class C(XY): pass
def some_function(arg: XY): pass
```

But I am not sure if it would be worthwhile to define a new class only for type hint, which doesn't effect runtime anyway.

How do we create a type hint for any class that is a subclass of both `X` **and** `Y`?

Comment: A generic type is a class with one or more type variables. I don't think I'm talking about generic types.

Comment: For future readers, I'd like to highlight that python protocols support exactly what is asked here, albeit with a slightly ugly syntax. You can see an example here: https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#unions-and-intersections-of-protocols . You can basically ask for a mix of interfaces at will, like with traits in rust or type classes in haskell. This idea is really powerful and the current answer doesn't really highlight this enough IMHO.

Comment: We have no explicit type intersection construct as of now. It has been elaborated on though: Guido mentioned a `Intersection[t1, t2, …]` companion to `Union` as a "We might add" [in 2014](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#fundamental-building-blocks). Also, the Protocol PEP (2017) mentioned a `Proto = All[Proto1, Proto2, ...]`construct [as a rejected idea](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#provide-a-special-intersection-type-construct), commenting that it could easily be added in the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python type hints does not support explicit *intersection* annotation. But you have at least two workarounds:

You could introduce a **mix** class, e.g:

```
class A:
    def foo_a(self):
        pass

class B:
    def foo_b(self):
        pass
    

class Mix(A, B):
    pass


def foo(p: Mix) -> None:
    p.foo_a()
    p.foo_b()
```

Or use structural subtyping, `Protocol`, e.g.:

```
from typing import Protocol

class Supports_ab(Protocol):
    def a(self):
        pass
    
    def b(self):
        pass

class A:
    def a(self):
        pass

class B:
    def b(self):
        pass

class Derived(A, B):
    pass

    
class SomeClassAB:  # no need superclass
    def a(self):
        pass
    
    def b(self):
        pass
    
def foo(p: Supports_ab) -> None:
    p.a()
    p.b()

foo(SomeClassAB())
foo(Derived())
```

Comment: Interesting! `Protocol` is pretty close to what I am looking for.