# What's "and" operator for type hints in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-3.9, python-typing

I'm going to make a "type alias" for a combination of several types. I can create a new class for most types, but this makes the code too long and type checkers can't show it. I'm looking for a better alternative. we can use [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) for `A | B` but I need `A & B`.

Example:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


class Identify:
    id: int


def test_type_hints(obj: T) -> T & Identify:  # This Line
    obj.id = id(obj)
```

If I can do it, How? else Why?

Comment: `Union[Iterable, Iterator, Sized]` ?

Comment: I need "and" not "or"

Comment: Shorter than 1 line? And no, you can't. (but also note that you apparently want `typing.Collection` and that `Iterator` already implies `Itearble`)

Comment: ok thanks. but I hope and wait again for a new type alias on v3.12

Comment: `Iterator` and `Sized` are nearly mutually exclusive. It's technically possible to implement both in the same type, but it's a bad idea and almost no iterators do it.

Comment: But it can be effective for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - specify type with multiple bases (typing AND operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108452/python-specify-type-with-multiple-bases-typing-and-operator)

Comment: Are you intending for the logic of your code to make `obj` into an `Identity` object for purposes other than type checking? Because just adding an attribute won't do that. If you were to do `isinstance(obj, Identity)` at the end of the test function it would be `False`. Perhaps `Identity` is supposed to be a `Protocol`?

Comment: Maybe you are right. But I have a problem with how to use it here. Please explain in the form of a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show doesn't actually turn `obj` into an instance of `Identify`, so the type hint you're asking to add would be misleading. Calling `isinstance(obj, Identify)` would be false, at runtime, and no type checking declarations would accept the object as an instance of the class.

If you want the `Identify` type not to be a real type that expects you to subclass and make instances of it, but just a signifier for "an object with an `id` attribute", then you should make it a `typing.Protocol`. A protocol does just what you want, it lets you describe the features an object must have, and any such object, of any type, will be accepted wherever the an object obeying the protocol is expected.

```
from typing import Protocol

class Identify(typing.Protocol):
    id: int

class MyObj:
    pass
    
o = MyObj()
print(isinstance(o, Identify)) # prints False

o.id = 2
print(isinstance(o, Identify)) # prints True now
```

This doesn't exactly solve your issue though, as there's not really a mechanism in Python type hinting to dynamically declare an intersection of types (it's been [a requested feature for a long time](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213)). A crude approach that might work for some situations would be to discard the old type information and just preserve the new knowledge of the protocol, but this might not be good enough for your use case:

```
def test_type_hints(obj: typing.Any) -> Identify:
    obj.id = id(obj)
    return obj
```

Comment: This method does not reach my goal. I want the type checker to work in the best possible way, this method destroys the other properties of the object. but thanks you for answer it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I initially just commented about using `Protocol`. My answer is mostly *you can't do that* (yet). `Protocol` partially addresses one corner of your problem, but not the whole thing. You really need intersection types and they don't exist.

Comment: So I'm looking for a way to suggest the best "mothed" and "attributes". Because there is no other answer, I will mark this answer as the correct answer for now.